# Generate DrawIO / jGraph Diagram from CSV Programmatically?

Tags: draw.io

This feels like it should be possible. But I've not managed to find out how just yet.

To achieve this via the desktop application it's simple;

1. Use the Arrange > Insert > Advanced > CSV option
2. Diagram generated
3. Export to HTML or SVG
4. Open up in Chrome

I want to achieve this programmatically because the data that is entered as part of Step 1 will be created on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible at time of writing - https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/issues/591

**Update**
"this was recently fixed since v20.7.4 (github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/issues/…) –
Exodus 4D"

Comment: Regarding the comments this was recently fixed since v20.7.4 (https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/issues/202#issuecomment-1367626037)